# Calculating density within a shapefile (in R)

Tags: r, sf, sp, density

I'm trying to calculate density within a shapefile, but I'm fairly confident I'm doing it wrong. The idea is to figure out in which geographical regions there have been the most sales by density.

[Here is a link to the file that I use (testdata.shp)](https://github.com/gooponyagrinch/blob)

```
library(sf)

sample <- st_read("testdata.shp")

sample$area <- st_area(sample$geometry)

density_calc <-sample %>% st_buffer(0) %>% group_by(areas) %>% summarise(`Sales (density)` = sum(sales)/sum(area))
```

Here are the details of the shapefile:

```
Geometry set for 2106 features 
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -120.0065 ymin: 35.00184 xmax: -114.0396 ymax: 42.00221
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

I guess my issue is, I don't really know what is right and wrong, so I have no clue if I did it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the number of sales per area unit, your code works fine. Although you could also just run

```
sample$density <- sample$sales / sample$area
```

instead. Word of caution: there are `NA` values in your data, be careful you interpret them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you just want the sales-by-area (mass per unit volume) just divide the sales column by the results of `st_area`. Normally, MULTI part geometries can yield unreliable results, and can be addressed using sf::st_cast(x, "POLYGON") but, with this specific data it looks like counties are being aggregated because they are comprised of multiple parts so, the correct areas would be the entire counties polygon and not its pieces-and-parts. This data has 2106 MULTIPOLYGON (multipart) and 2115 POLYGON (single part) so, 9 aggregated polygons.

I am not sure how useful these results are going to be and you do have numerous NA's in the sales column (16%). In the rural west it seems like you would need a variable that indicates potential, many of the Nevada counties are pretty empty so, would not be statistically comparable to the counties containing say, Las Vegas and Reno. Perhaps an adjustment by population density.

```
library(sf)   
sample <- sf::st_read("testdata.shp")
cat("Proportion missing values", 
    length(which(is.na(sample$sales))) / nrow(sample), "\n")
  sample$area <- sf::st_area(sample$geometry)
    sample$density <- sample$sales / sample$area

plot(sample[c("sales","area","density")])
```